# ActionBarSherlock Theme Installed, Still get Theme Crash

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock

Here is LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.---.---/com.---.---.ManageDebts}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1003)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:915)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:849)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity.setContentView(SherlockListActivity.java:229)
at com.kickinglettuce.debtplanner.ManageDebts.onCreate(ManageDebts.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
... 11 more
```

It says I need to use the specific Sherlock theme, well, here is what I am doing:

**in Manifest:**

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/DPFTheme" >
```

**Res folder Values/Styles:**

```
 <style name="DPFTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" />
```

**Res folder Values-v11/Styles:**

I believe I have all the bases covered.  Or do I?

```
  <style name="DPFTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
```

Now, this app has several thousand users and I have only seen this error about 5 times or so.  So maybe it is device specific? I am not sure.

Comment: It does not crash always? Only on some devices? Strange...

Comment: Works perfect on every device and emulator I have tested. So curious what error means.

Comment: What devices did it happen on? It's likely an OEM-specific ROM that's causing theme issues.

Comment: The only one that it showed on the Console was an Acer tablet. The others said "Other".

Comment: Received several more errors from this.  No model numbers except for the one AT100 (I was wrong in above comment, it's a Toshiba Tablet).  No one is really complaining so I have to assume this is an unfixable problem for a very small minority.  The AT100 is an international version of Toshiba Thrive.  I am wondering if this is still on Honeycomb.

Comment: @JakeWharton If I just set the theme of the entire app to Theme.Sherlock, I'm thinking that will solve this?  Right now, It is set that way if it is version 2.x of Android.  3.x and higher, use more of a the defaults... does this make sense?

Comment: Did you use this to create your theme ? http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100